# How to update the Google chart with events?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google API to draw chart set event that whenever my button clicked one value of my chart will change but unfortunately nothing happened so is there any page to update Google without reload the page?
Google Chart Link
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline
Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization',
       'version':'1','packages':['timeline']}]}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var test=10;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#test").click(function(){
                alert("Awd");
                test = 12;
            });
        });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var container = document.getElementById('example5.3');
            var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Room' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
            dataTable.addRows([
                [ 'Magnolia Room',  'CSS Fundamentals',    new Date(0,0,0,test,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
                [ 'Magnolia Room',  'Intro JavaScript',    new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
                [ 'Magnolia Room',  'Advanced JavaScript', new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,19,0,0) ],
                [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Intermediate Perl',   new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
                [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Advanced Perl',       new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
                [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Applied Perl',        new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,18,0,0) ],
                [ 'Petunia Room',   'Google Charts',       new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
                [ 'Petunia Room',   'Closure',             new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
                [ 'Petunia Room',   'App Engine',          new Date(0,0,0,21,30,0), new Date(0,0,1,0,30,0) ]]);

            var options = {
                timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true },
                backgroundColor: '#ffd'
            };

            chart.draw(dataTable, options);
        }
    </script>
```

And Html :

```
<html>
<body>
<button id="test" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
    <div id="example5.3" style="width: 900px; height: 200px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your event handler change the value of in the DataTable and then redraw the chart:

```
function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('example5.3');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Room' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
        [ 'Magnolia Room',  'CSS Fundamentals',    new Date(0,0,0,10,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
        [ 'Magnolia Room',  'Intro JavaScript',    new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
        [ 'Magnolia Room',  'Advanced JavaScript', new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,19,0,0) ],
        [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Intermediate Perl',   new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
        [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Advanced Perl',       new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
        [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Applied Perl',        new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,18,0,0) ],
        [ 'Petunia Room',   'Google Charts',       new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
        [ 'Petunia Room',   'Closure',             new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
        [ 'Petunia Room',   'App Engine',          new Date(0,0,0,21,30,0), new Date(0,0,1,0,30,0) ]]);

    var options = {
        timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true },
        backgroundColor: '#ffd'
    };

    $("#test").click(function(){
        alert("Awd");
        var date = dataTable.getValue(0, 2); // get "start" date in row 0
        date.setHours(12); // change the hour
        dataTable.setValue(0, 2, date); // set the "start" date of row 0
        chart.draw(dataTable, options); // redraw the chart
    });

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

see working example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/xnKzJ/

Comment: Thanks for the answer do you why when we change the status of the chart the rectangles change but the description did't change and stuck in the last place????

Comment: What do you mean by "the description didn't change and stuck in the last place"?  The only change in the chart was the start time of the first event, so that is the only thing that should change.